# How Does SignalR C# Invoke Methods

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr

I am looking to see if anyone knows how the javascript is able to invoke the server side methods at runtime, similar to how SignalR achieves this.  The reason is, I would like to adopt this same type of architecture in my code to remove switch statements that end up calling the appropriate methods.

So basically now I have a C# WebMethod called Execute, and it takes a string parameter that then selects the appropriate method through a switch.

```
public void Execute(string Method)
{
    switch (Method)
    {
        case "doThis":
           doThis();
        break;
    }

}
```

It would be nice to have a similar style of dynamically calling my C# method from javascript and the proper method is then invoked.  Any ideas?

Also I am hoping someone could go in depth other than just saying, "Look at the source".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How Does SignalR C# Invoke Methods

Depends on the protocol , but lets say your browser ( and the server)  support webSocket protocol :

You send (via javascript) a message  :

`var socket = new WebSocket("ws://...");` // required server side function token is here as a param(+params)

The server can ( fw4.5 )  handle this message and by `reflection` ,  `dynamic`  -- it invokes the method.

However , there is a catch ( by design) it executes - **asynchronously** :

So this code will **not** work :

```
var a=1;
var b=2;
var c=myHBub.server.add(a,b);
alert(c) // undefined.
```

While this one will work.:

```
var a=1;
var b=2;
myHBub.server.add(a,b).done(function (result){alert(result);});
```

---

As for where does it happens and how ?

I executed a Js client metho named "Join" :

and here is the core executor :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf9Fz.jpg

[image]

Comment: I understand how the javascript side works, I am more interested in what is happening on the server side when it receives this message.  Could you go into more detail on the 'reflection' and 'dynamic' portions?

Answer (score 1):

Drew Marsh is right that SignalR builds and compiles a lambda expressions to call C# hub methods, but that is probably more complicated than what is necessary. All you really need is simple reflection along the following lines:

```
public void Execute(string Method)
{
    GetType().GetMethod(Method).Invoke(this, new object[]{});
}
```

SignalR uses compiled lambda expressions to get better performance, but for your scenario it might not be necessary.

The code for expression compilation had already been written for ASP.NET MVC where it is called `ActionMethodDispatcher`, but it wasn't added to SignalR until v1.1.0. I only saw a ~1% overall performance gain for basic hub invocation using expression compilation over [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx). Profiling showed most of the time spent invoking SignalR hub methods is spent doing JSON serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

The code is completely open source, why don't you go have a look? Specifically you'll want to start looking in [HubDispatcher::OnReceived](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubDispatcher.cs#L143) where the messages come in and trace you're way all the way through [DefaultHubManager](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/DefaultHubManager.cs) and ultimately you'll make you're way down into [HubMethodDispatcher](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/HubMethodDispatcher.cs) where the magic all happens.

Ultimately the answer to your question is that it builds a lambda expression, using [`Expression::Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda.aspx), to invoke the method and compiles that into a strongly typed delegate of type `HubMethodExecutor(IHub, object[])` by calling [`Expression::Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx).